# Remove a dictionary key that has a certain value

Tags: python

I know dictionary's are not meant to be used this way, so there is no built in function to help do this, but I need to delete every entry in my dictionary that has a specific value.

so if my dictionary looks like:

```
'NameofEntry1': '0'
'NameofEntry2': 'DNC'
 ...
```

I need to delete(probably pop) all the entries that have value DNC, there are multiple in the dictionary.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Modifying the original dict:

```
for k,v in your_dict.items():
    if v == 'DNC':
       del your_dict[k]
```

or create a new dict using dict comprehension:

```
your_dict = {k:v for k,v in your_dict.items() if v != 'DNC'}
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) on `iteritems()`,`iterkeys()` and `itervalues()`:

> Using `iteritems()`, `iterkeys()` or `itervalues()` while adding or
>   deleting entries in the dictionary may raise a `RuntimeError` or fail
>   to iterate over all entries.

Same applies to the normal `for key in dict:` loop.

In Python 3 this is applicable to  `dict.keys()`, `dict.values()` and `dict.items()`.

Comment: I get `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

Comment: @Climbs_lika_Spyder Check the statement about Python 3 in last line.

Comment: In Python 3, you need `list(d.items())` as mentioned in @jared's answer.

Answer (score 10):

You just need to make sure that you aren't modifying the dictionary while you are iterating over it else you would get `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`.

So you need to iterate over a copy of the keys, values (for `d` use `d.items()` in 2.x or `list(d.items())` in 3.x)

```
>>> d = {'NameofEntry1': '0', 'NameofEntry2': 'DNC'}
>>> for k,v in d.items():
...     if v == 'DNC':
...         del d[k]
... 
>>> d
{'NameofEntry1': '0'}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
for key, value in dic.items():
     if value == 'DNC':
         dic.pop(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

If restrictions re: modifying the dictionary while iterating on it is a problem, you could create a new class compatible with dict that stores a reverse index of all keys that have the given value (updated at create / update / delete of dict item), which can be arguments to del without iterating over the dict's items.

Subclass dict, and override `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, `pop`, `popitem` and `clear`.

If this is an operation you're doing a lot of, that might be convenient and fast.